# Data turns Nil when passing from previous View Controller going to another View Controller using Segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am about to pass data from a *ViewController* going to another *ViewController* using segue. When checking the data(event) from a variable thru breakpoint in the *1st View Controller* the data(event) is not nil. But when I checked the *2nd View Controller* the data(event) is *nil*. I am confuse whether if the reason is, I have error in my codes or because of the error appeared in my console that says **Unable to insert COPY_SEND**. Hope I can get some help from you. Thank you

[image: First View Controller showing the Event and Passcode have Data]

[image: Second View Controller showing the Event and Passcode are NIL]

**Segue from First View Controller**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DashBoardViewController" {
        let dashBoardController = segue.destination as! DashBoardViewController
        dashBoardController.self.event = event
        dashBoardController.self.passcode = passcode
    }
}
```

**Event and Passcode Turns Nil**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard event != nil, passcode != nil else {
        _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("No Event Details", subTitle: "There's no event details, please logout and try again")
        return
    }
    showEventDetails()
}
```

**showEventDetails**

```
func showEventDetails() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.eventNameLabel.text =  "\(self.event.name.uppercased())"
        self.locationLabel.text =  "\(self.event.location.uppercased())"
        if let dateStringFromDate = getFormattedStringFromDate(date: (self.event.startDateTime), formatString: "MMMM dd, yyyy/ hh:mm a") {
            self.dateTimeLabel.text = dateStringFromDate
        } else {
            self.dateTimeLabel.text = "-"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use your code and it works fine. Try to check your values separately. Share you full code and then I can help.

Comment: @AlexKolovatov What's wrong with my codes? _Unable to insert COPY_SEND_ error appears in my console.. Is that the error? How can I share to you my codes?

Comment: just archive your project and put into dropbox then send me a link .

Comment: @AlexKolovatov https://github.com/pdgoyal/RegistrAsian is this okay?

Comment: Yes, its ok. I will check your code little bit later.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you linked the segue which goes to **DashBoardViewController** on your submitButton by Interface Builder, which means when you are tapping on the submit button, the  `@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: UIButton) { }` gets called, where you check if your **passcode** is good to go and if so you are calling `validateEventPasscode()` which calls an API endpoint (asynchronous) and only there you are populating the `self.event = event` (line 187 in ViewController.swift).

Now, what really happens is that when you link a segue from a button by IB (interface builder), there will be a perform segue internally which we have to stop by overriding the following method in **ViewController.swift**: [source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621502-shouldperformsegue)

```
func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, 
                 sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

This way your call from line 190 - ViewController.swift:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showEventDashboard", sender: self)
```

is the one that fires:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "DashBoardViewController" {
         let dashBoardController = segue.destination as!  DashBoardViewController
         dashBoardController.event = event
         dashBoardController.passcode = passcode
     }
   }
```

You can test my theory by placing three breakpoints in **ViewController.swift**:

1. line 134 at validateEventPasscode() from submitButton IBAction func;
2. line 190 at self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showEventDashboard", sender: self) from validateEventPasscode() func;
3. line 108 at dashBoardController.event = event from prepare(for segue, sender) func;

Buggy order of execution: 1, 3, 2 - at the moment this I would expect if my theory is correct;
Desired order of execution: 1, 2, 3.

Long story short, you populate your `self.event` after you `perfomSegue` and go to the **next screen**, that's why your `event` is **nil** in the next **VC**.

I used as reference the ViewController.swift file from your repo: [ViewController.swift](https://github.com/pdgoyal/RegistrAsian/blob/master/ViewController.swift)

Hope it helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your prepareForSegue method in FirstViewController with this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DashBoardViewController" {
        let dashBoardController = segue.destination as! DashBoardViewController
        dashBoardController.event = event
        dashBoardController.passcode = passcode
    }
}
```

you don't need to write

```
dashBoardController.self.event = event
dashBoardController.self.passcode = passcode
```

Just remove **self** from above two lines.

Comment: can you tell me why you use dashBoardController.self.event instead of dashBoardController.event

Comment: Its not my question and I don't do that but problem isn't here. I've just checked.

Comment: @MuhammadKhaliqurRehman I tried your suggested solution but it doesn't work for me.